# How To Store Items From a Shopping List

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building an expense tracker

```
class ShoppingList
   has_many :items
end

class Item
end
```

but I am not quite sure, how to store the items. My ideas so far:

**First**

```
Item.new(name: 'milk', price: 1)
Item.new(name: 'chocolate', price 2)
```

This would be simple, however the same thing might end up with different names.

```
Item.new(name: 'biscuits', price: 3)
Item.new(name: 'cookies', price: 3)
```

**Second**

```
class Milk < Item; end
class Chocolate < Item; end

Milk.new(price: 1)
```

This feels a bit complicated, a class would have to be added everytime you buy something new - on the other hand, once done - I imagine things would be easier to search for.

What is correct way of solving this? What are the respective advantages/disadvantages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're first method is definitely more on point. If you have worries about their being aliases for a name you can even include another table

```
class Item
    has_many :alternate_names
end
```

and then look up the item you are saving in the alternate names table, which you would have to create, and take that relation back to the item. So for input name:"biscuits", price:3 you could do something like

```
> alternatesearch = AlternateName.find_by(name: "biscuits")
   => #<AlternateName id: 5, item_id: 2, name: "biscuits">
> Item.find(alternatesearch.item_id)
   => #<Item id:2 name:"cookies" price:"3">
```

or if its a new one item you could use a find or create by on the alternatesearch and then create a new Item if it creates it. I am sort of confused on exactly what you are looking to do with the shopping list or if you want to add new items every time or reuse them but change the price.

I think this is better than the second method because the second method is very limiting in the number of items it could have and you would basically be saving your db info in the rb class files, which is going to make it very hard to change. But I suppose that could be an advantage depending on how many items you want to have.